# How to start a kotlin coroutine on current thread from non-coroutine world?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

I have a function :

```
fun login(..., cb:Callback){ // this function is invoked from non-coroutine world
    // 1)  current Thread "workThread"
    scope.launch { // I have tried all Dispathers to create the scope, but cannot achieve what i want
        // 2) i want current Thread still "workThread"
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            // do something
        }
        // 3) i want resume executing on "workThread"
        cb.callback(...)
    }
}
```

What i tried and what i want have noted in the comment in detail. so how can i achieve it? Thanks in advance.

thanks for all the replies. because of the comment length limit, i append the content here.

For my question,I think the point is not about thread pool or block? Coroutine can also work on a single thread, a android demo is bellow:

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    Log("1")
    MainScope().launch {
        Log("2")
        delay(100)
        Log("3")
    }
    Log("4")
    ...
```

this will print 1 4 2 3.
the point is i have create a coroutine from current thread(main thread), as long as entered the coroutine world, the rest is simple. i can launch another coroutine to do heavy work like this:

```
    Log("1") // main thread
    MainScope().launch { // a coroutine work on main thread
        Log("2") 
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            // some heavy work
        }
        Log("3")  // resume on main thread
    }
    Log("4")
```

the above is exactly what i want. i don't know why android's main thread(with Mainscope) can work like this, but my work thread cannot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MainScope()` is a function that creates a CoroutineScope that uses Dispatchers.Main as the dispatcher attached to its parent Job, so its coroutines run on the main thread by default. On Android, Dispatchers.Main works by breaking up coroutine Continuations into Runnables that are submitted as messages to a Handler in the Android main thread’s Looper. Android on its own doesn’t know anything about Kotlin or coroutines, but all the building blocks were already there to be able to install a dispatcher on its main thread.

The fact that the Android main thread is a LooperThread that has a Looper that is infinitely looping in that thread and accepts work to be posted to it is why you can launch coroutines on it asynchronously. This is not possible with any arbitrary thread. On Android, it is possible with arbitrary LooperThreads, by creating a Handler that uses that Looper and wrapping it using `asCoroutineDispatcher()`. You can also do this with Executors, since they have their own thread pools. If you wanted a dedicated thread for running coroutines you could do this with a single-threaded Executor.

`runBlocking` is the only way to run a coroutine on an arbitrary thread of any kind. It actually internally creates its own Dispatcher that runs on that thread by creating its own temporary loop that will only run until `runBlocking` returns. So it can launch parallel asynchronous coroutines but has to wait for them before returning. There’s no way it could install this loop externally to itself.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer. According to your words, bellow is my understanding:
Coroutine essentially a runnable code block that can be executed somewhere. the 'somewhere' is the thread looper.
main thread in android can start coroutine on it, because it has the looper already. an arbitrary thread can not because it has no looper and no way to externally add a looper into it. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes, that's basically right, except a coroutine is not just one runnable code block. It's broken up into multiple pieces if it suspends. When it suspends, that's a break between pieces of work that can be submitted to be run on a thread. That's how it avoids blocking a thread during a delay, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

To start a coroutine on the current thread, use runBlocking function:

```
fun login(..., cb:Callback){ // this function is invoked from non-coroutine world
    // 1)  current Thread "workThread"
    runBlocking {
        // 2) i want current Thread still "workThread"
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            // do something
        }
        // 3) i want resume executing on "workThread"
        cb.callback(...)
    }
}
```

Comment: @S P Thanks for your reply. But I don't want to block current thread. Is there another approach？

Comment: There is no other way to do it. A coroutine is only able to run without blocking on a thread because the threads that it uses are set up to be members of thread pools. They have loops that accept continuation work to process. You can’t turn the current thread into one that has all of that built in.

Comment: This is why Kotlin apps that use coroutines tend to use `runBlocking` in `main` - it basically runs *everything* inside that coroutine world, making them available everywhere. And that way, the only thing being blocked is `main` finishing and the program ending. You could try doing the same for *workThread* (wrap its contents in `runBlocking`) or if you can't do that, you might have to just launch another thread instead of using coroutines